# How can I display all the ticklabels of the x-axis with categories in an asp.net chart?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, charts

I am making a chart with asp.net. The y-axis represents the number of users, and the x-axis represents the user name. When the chart is drawn with the code below, only some of the user names on the x-axis appear. I want all user names to be displayed on the x-axis. What settings do I need to add?

```
<asp:Chart ID="chart1" runat="server">
    <series>
        <asp:Series Name="series_user"></asp:Series>
    </series>
    <chartareas>
        <asp:ChartArea Name="chartArea_user">
        </asp:ChartArea>
    </chartareas>
</asp:Chart>



//styling
Chart cht = this.chart1;
string chartAreaName = "chartArea_user";
width = 800
height = 500
string title = "user_cnt"

cht.Width = width;
cht.Height = height;
cht.Titles.Add(title);
            
cht.ChartAreas[chartAreaName].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
cht.ChartAreas[chartAreaName].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 1;
cht.ChartAreas[chartAreaName].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Gray;
cht.ChartAreas[chartAreaName].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash;
cht.ChartAreas[chartAreaName].AxisX.Title = xtitle;
cht.ChartAreas[chartAreaName].AxisX.TitleFont = new Font("Malgun Gothic", 10);
cht.ChartAreas[chartAreaName].AxisY.Title = ytitle;
cht.ChartAreas[chartAreaName].AxisY.TitleFont = new Font("Malgun Gothic", 10);
cht.BorderlineColor = Color.Gray;
cht.BorderlineWidth = 1;
cht.BorderlineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
```

In the picture below, the user name appears at two-space intervals. But I want all usernames to be displayed on the x-axis.

[image]